# How do Multimodal LLMs of 2023 score on the ARC benchmark (in 2020: 20% Accuracy)

Tags: papers, agi, benchmarks

Q: **I wonder if anyone has tried to solve the ARC tasks with one of the state-of-the-art Multimodal LLMs?**
**Can LLMs that can process graphics input do the following?**

> (This question is **not** about the The AI2’s Reasoning Challenge (ARC) dataset, a multiple-choice question-answering dataset, containing questions from science exams from grade 3 to grade 9.)

Background:
I came across a paper from 2019 ["On the Measure of Intelligence"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.01547) by Francois Chollet who is a Researcher at Google, Creator of the Keras Deep Learning Library.

In that paper he proposed the Abstraction and Reasoning Corpus, ARC. Actually you can view this as  a Benchmark that consists of solving 400 graphical reasoning puzzles,  to test AI systems' abstraction and analogy abilities.

To illustrate, here is an example from the paper:

[image]

(A machine must infer what to do (transforming a test picture without seeing a "result" picture on the right) from ~3 similar training imagepairs per task)-

2020 state of the art:
In 2020 there was a Kaggle Competition and the [1st place solution](https://www.kaggle.com/code/icecuber/arc-1st-place-solution/notebook) got 20% of the 400 task right. ([Leaderboard](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/abstraction-and-reasoning-challenge/leaderboard) Score in competition was "Percentage still wrong" or something - so lowest score of 79.4% won)
The  [C++ code](https://github.com/top-quarks/ARC-solution) contains special-purpose image manipulation and inference routines, carefully crafted and combined as described in a [write-up](https://www.kaggle.com/c/abstraction-and-reasoning-challenge/discussion/154597) by the author "icecuber".

Now it's 2023 and OpenAI is making GPT-4V multimodal generally available.

In April 2023 someone asked a similar question on the [OpenAI discussion forum](https://community.openai.com/t/gpt-4-and-the-arc-challenge/168955); no answers. That post was written independently from this one,  and I just discovered that post right before submitting this post.

**Yesterday I have  given ChatGPT-4 Advanced Data Analysis a single example, and the LLM quickly [solved](https://chat.openai.com/share/02cb360e-8f42-4932-b764-8b57c36167b2) the puzzle shown below;** sort of. Admittedly, my prompt was  in sloppy natural language, and I uploaded 3 badly cropped training images as input.

Task f8c80d96:

[image: f8c80d96-demo-3]

With human intelligence I was not able to infer the solution to task f8c80d96 easily. Made 3 wrong guesses.
(Solution: Add 1 vertical yellow line but also replace black background with grey background)

Clearly my attempt is not a systematic study, just practice.
To conclude, I suspect if GPT-4 can solve 1 task, it can solve many more than 20% of those 400 examples, e.g. when using the API with carefully designed prompts and instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gathered a [few notes](https://github.com/neoneye/arc-notes/tree/main/awesome) about ARC, with links to projects that use LLMs. Too many links to post them all here.

AFAIK [Jack Cole+Mohamed Osman](https://lab42.global/community-post-model-efficiency/) solves around 21 of the 100 hidden tasks. This is SOTA with LLMs and the hidden dataset.